# AIR app in front of Keynote presentation

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, air

Does anyone know of a way to make an AIR app display over top of a Keynote presentation?

I currently have alwaysInFront set to true.

Thanks for any help,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think keynote in presentation mode will always throw itself to the top. This is to prevent accidents in the middle of a presentation to a board of CEO etc.

Your best asset might be CMD+tab to your air app when required.